# How to simulate Java generic wildcards in C#

Tags: java, c#, generics, wildcard

The following Java code compares the average of two arrays, one of Integers and one of Doubles.

```
class Generic_Class<T extends Number>
{
    T[] nums; // array of Number or subclass

    Generic_Class(T[] o)
    {
        nums = o;
    }

    // Return type double in all cases.
    double average()
    {
        double sum = 0.0;

        for(int i=0; i < nums.length; i++)
            sum += nums[i].doubleValue();

        return sum / nums.length;
    }


//  boolean sameAvg(Generic_Class<T> ob)
//  Using Generic_Class<T> i get the error:
//  incompatible types: Generic_Class<Double> cannot be converted to Generic_Class<Integer>

//  Using wilcards I get no error
    boolean sameAvg(Generic_Class<?> ob)
    {
        if(average() == ob.average())
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

The main method is like this:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Integer inums[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    Double  dnums[] = { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0 };

    Generic_Class<Integer> iob = new Generic_Class<Integer>(inums);
    Generic_Class<Double>  dob = new Generic_Class<Double>(dnums);

    System.out.println("iob average is " + iob.average());
    System.out.println("dob average is " + dob.average());

    if (iob.sameAvg(dob))
        System.out.println("Averages of iob and dob are the same.");
    else
        System.out.println("Averages of iob and dob differ.");
}
```

The result is:

```
iob average is 3.0
dob average is 3.0
Averages of iob and dob are the same.
```

I've tried to do the same in C# but, since I have no wildcards, I can't accomplish the same task.

How can I do the same with C# ?

Thank you.

Comment: This doesn't look like c#. Is it Java?

Comment: @ZoharPeled, yes it's Java. I've edited the code a few seconds ago.

Comment: I've edited your title and added the java tag to make your question clearer.

Comment: You haven't shown  your C# code, or described how, specifically, it's not working.

Comment: `sameAvg` code can be simplified to `return average() == ob.average();`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As other answerers have said, there is no equivalent of `Number` in C#. The best you can get is `struct, IConvertible`. However, there is another way of doing the generic wildcard.

Just use another generic parameter:

```
public class Generic_Class<T> where T : struct, IConvertible
{
    T[] nums;
    public Generic_Class(T[] o)
    {
        nums = o;
    }

    public double Average()
    {
        double sum = 0.0;
        for(int i=0; i < nums.Length; i++)
            sum += nums[i].ToDouble(null);
        return sum / nums.Length;
    }

    // this is the important bit
    public bool SameAvg<U>(Generic_Class<U> ob) where U : struct, IConvertible
    {
        if(Average() == ob.Average())
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking the same thing and implemented a fiddle here https://dotnetfiddle.net/AAMngv

Comment: I was thinking the same 50 minutes earlier ;)

Comment: To elaborate: the Java version is shorthand for this, since wildcards implicitly include type parameter bounds. `Generic_Class<?>` is equivalent to `Generic_Class<? extends Number>`, and that method parameter is essentially shorthand for `<U extends Number> boolean sameAvg(Generic_Class<U> ob)`, which is analogous to the C# version.

Comment: I've changed the **where U : struct, IConvertible** to **where U : IConvertible** and works. Why do we nedd the **struct** constraint?

Comment: @user9559069 because c# does not have an equivalent of `Number`. The closest we can get to that is constraining `U` to be both a struct and an implementer of `IConvertible`.

Answer (score 4):

Taking the average of a sequence of numbers is built-in to C#:

```
var iNums = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var dNums = new double[] { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0 };

var iAvg = iNums.Average();
var dAvg = dNums.Average();
var areEqual = iAvg == dAvg;
```

`areEqual == true` after running the above.

You can even do this with complex types using the `Average` overload that takes a `Func<TSource, T>` to return a value:

```
public class MyValue
{
    private static Random rnd = new Random();

    public int SomeInt { get; set; } = rnd.Next();
}

var myObjArray = new MyValue[] { new MyValue(), new MyValue(), new MyValue(), new MyValue() };

var myAvg = myObjArray.Average(o => o.SomeInt);
```

So no, wildcards are not available in C#, but using Generics you can simulate wildcards by having multiple overloads of the `Func` in this case.

See [IEnumerable Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable?view=netframework-4.7.1)

Comment: Great! Like it!

Comment: A good point! Changing the implementation is better than trying to shoehorn in a feature that doesn’t exist in then language!

Comment: PS there IS a way to express wildcards in C#... but as far as I remember only for typeof expressions `typeof(Generic<>)` but I don’t think that’s useful here

Comment: @series0ne That really isn't a "wildcard" like Java, it is a generic type reference with a single type parameter. It can only ever evaluate to a single generic type, not an implementation.

Comment: I know, I’m not on form today. IIRC it basically just gets the System.Type instance for the generic type without specifying the GTP. So yes, it’s not a wildcard like in Java.

Answer (score 2):

Just add simple interface with method `double Average` so you can do:

```
interface IAbleToGetAverage 
{
    double Average();
}

class GenericClass<T> : IAbleToGetAverage
    where T : struct, IConvertible
{
    private readonly T[] nums; // array of Number or subclass

    public GenericClass(T[] o)
    {
        nums = o;
    }


    private readonly IFormatProvider formatProvider = new NumberFormatInfo();

    public double Average()
    {
        var sum = 0.0;

        for(var i=0; i < nums.Length; i++)
            sum += nums[i].ToDouble(formatProvider);

        return sum / nums.Length;
    }


    public bool SameAvg(IAbleToGetAverage ob)
    {
        if(Math.Abs(Average() - ob.Average()) < double.Epsilon)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: And... how would you make the .net framework int and double arrays implement that interface, might I ask?

Comment: @ZoharPeled...beat me to it! XD

Comment: @ZoharPeled They don't need to. They just need their `Generic_Class` to implement it.

Comment: Generic_Class shuld implement IAbleToGetAverage

Comment: @Servy and gabba you are correct, sorry. I've must have misread something.

Comment: But how can you express `T extends Number` in C#?

Comment: @Ripple, thanks for point me. This shuld help where T : struct, IConvertible

Comment: @gabba you wrote a mix of Java and C# code: **class Generic_Class<T extends Number> : IAbleToGetAverage** <= what's this

Comment: And how would `T.doubleValue()` go?

Comment: @gabba did you run you code? It seems that some methods they don't exist in C#.

Comment: This code won't work. This is a very poor answer, I'm afraid.

Comment: @series0ne, yeah I did't refactor code, I just show a way. But Now I provide working example

Comment: @gabba this solution would "work" with DateTime, Guid, TimeSpan...because they're all IConvertible and struct, but are they numbers? - I'd be interested to see what it comes up with for the average of a range of DateTimes, or TimeSpans, or Guids - If you can test those cases, and your results are accurate, I'll upvote.

Comment: @series0ne, I think your arguments is about how to constraint this code to work only with "numeric" types. I agree with you on this point. Just runtime checks avalible. So you don't have to upvote. But I don't agree that is impossible.

Comment: @series0ne, if you need a static checks a C# way for it is make tons overriding methods with various types. So linq answer is about that.

Comment: @series0ne FYI, `Guid` and `TimeSpan` are not `IConvertible`.

Comment: @Ripple ah! I thought the majority of the basic .NET value types implemented IConvertible but I stand corrected.

Answer (score -2):

What you're expressing in your Java code is boxed numeric types, which all extend the `Number` class, so it's trivial to enforce a constraint that the generic type is a number.

Types work a little differently in C# because `int` rather that being primitive in the same sense as Java, is just a type alias for `System.Int32` which is a `struct`.

Also, there is no common base type (class, struct, interface, etc.) that is shared by ONLY numbers in C#, so its **IMPOSSIBLE** to create a constraint to enforce that the generic type is a number, has a numeric value, and therefore can have mathematical calculations performed on it.

Some suggestions here seem to be to use `where T : IComparable, struct` but I could argue that the constraint also applies to `DateTime`, `Guid` and `TimeSpan` - none of which are integral or floating point numbers.

Comment: seemingly impossible is possible

Comment: @gabba If you think so, then post an answer that actually accomplished it.  Considering you've posted an answer that doesn't work, it doesn't support your claim that it's possible.  If it were possible, why didn't you post an answer that actually does it?

Comment: @seriesOne, Servy  IConvertible not IComparable.
 IConvertible have ToDouble so any IConvertible type should correctly implement it